# ansible set variables conditionally in group_vars/all

Tags: ansible

i am trying to set global variables that will be valid to all playbooks

i am trying to set this global variable in group_vars/all file

i want to set one variable which can have multiple values depending to  the conditions

i have tried to use when conditions:

```
kdump_nfs:    'nfs1'
when: ansible_local.default_gateway.site == "site1"
kdump_nfs:      'nfs2'
when: ansible_local.default_gateway.site == "site2"
```

but getting :
[WARNING]: While constructing a mapping from /group_vars/all, line 1, column 1, found a duplicate dict key (kdump_nfs). Using last defined value only.

how can i set the variable "kdump_nfs" to get a deferent value depending of the condition

Answer (score 0):

Setting a changing variable at group vars will not be a good option. You can use the extra vars to pass the variable value that will be more dynamic.

For eg.

--extra-vars "var_name=${var_value}"

Comment: i dont want to use -extra-vars , i want to set the global variable as mentioned ,please advise

Comment: if the variable is changing as per the condition it won't be global variable. The best thing you can do is to create separate var files per condition

Comment: if i set the same variable name even with var files ,i a, still getting the   
found a duplicate dict key (file). Using last defined value only.
my goal is to set the same variable conditionally

Comment: using vars file you need to source that file only once to avoid over ridden of the variable files\

Comment: that is what i am doing in the playbook:

    name: add kdump nfs share to fstab
     include_vars:
      file: site1_kdump_nfs.yml
      name: kdump_nfs
      file: site2_kdump_nfs.yml
      name: kdump_nfs

i want the variable kdump_nfs valiue will be determined by the conditions in the variables files

Comment: you are including multiple files in same playbook which would be same. My suggestion is to have a single task that will source the conditional variable for e.g. name: add kdump to nfs include_vars: file: "{{ vars_file_name }}".yml

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat group_vars/all/main.yml 
my_variable: "{% if condition1 %}foo{% else %}bar{% endif %}"


$ cat site.yml 
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
  - name: site.yml --> Print debug variable
    debug:
      msg: "{{ my_variable }}"



$ ansible-playbook --connection=local --inventory 127.0.0.1, site.yml  --extra-vars "condition1=True"

PLAY [all] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************


TASK [site.yml --> Print debug variable] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": "foo"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: instead of passing the condition passing the value in extra vars would be more easier

Comment: there are multiple conditions , thus i dont want to use extra var, and i want those variables to be transparent to the users that will run those playbook ,what is the best way to assign the same variable conditionally ,without getting any warning messages?